# How to load JavaScript from parent html page to child page

Tags: javascript, html

My scenario is as this:-

**parent.html**

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjs.js"></script>
<body>
<a href="./child.html"> child </a>
</body>
</html>
```

**myjs.js**

```
function myFunction() {
  alert("I am an alert box!");
```

**child.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="">child button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I added JavaScript to the parent HTML and the parent has a link to the child HTML page. I want to call JavaScript function myFunction() from the child without adding the JavaScript in the child HTML. Is it possible to call the JavaScript function from the child without adding

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjs.js"></script>
```

Comment: There's no "parent" and "child" here, they are both simply pages.  One has a link which navigates to the other.  For any given page, any JavaScript you want to execute would need to be included in or referenced by that page.  Taking a step back, what's the goal here?  Why can't you put the JavaScript on the page that needs it?

Comment: @David, I would ask a question like this, but I have a question ban. His reason is probably because he would like to access local storage from one local file to another.